# Performing concurrent operations(Insert, retrieve data) in android sqlite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, concurrency

i want to ask a question related to performing concurrent operations like inserting bulk of data and retrieving data at the same time while data insert operation is going on. I have tried threads for this scenario but no success.

Below are two functions for inserting and retrieving data from sqlite table

```
public void insertData(List<ModelClass> list) {
        SQLiteDatabase dbase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        dbase.beginTransaction();
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            for (ModelClass bokmark : list) {
                values.put(KEY_FILE_NAME, bokmark.getFileName());
                values.put(KEY_FILE_URI, String.valueOf(bokmark.getFileUri()));
                values.put(KEY_FILE_PATH, String.valueOf(bokmark.getFilePath()));
                values.put(KEY_MONTH_NAME, bokmark.getMonthName());
                values.put(KEY_DATE, bokmark.getAudioDate());

                dbase.insert(TABLE_DETAIL, null, values);
            }
            dbase.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            dbase.endTransaction();
        }

        dbase.close();

    }
```

and below function for retrievel of data

```
public ArrayList<ModelClass> getAllData() {
        ArrayList<ModelClass> bookmarkList = new ArrayList<ModelClass>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DETAIL;
        //Log.e("selectQuery===>", "" + selectQuery);
        SQLiteDatabase dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ModelClass bokmarks = new ModelClass();
                bokmarks.setFileName(cursor.getString(1));
                bokmarks.setFileUri(Uri.parse(cursor.getString(2)));
                bokmarks.setFilePath(cursor.getString(3));
                bokmarks.setMonthName(cursor.getString(4));
                bokmarks.setAudioDate(cursor.getString(5));

                bookmarkList.add(bokmarks);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        dbase.close();

        return bookmarkList;
    }
```

On searching internet, some links suggest to use threads. i have tried with threads but no luck. Anyone have guidance related to this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **NOT** closing the database unless specifically required (say to backup the database as a single file if it is in WAL mode).

Whenever you open the database it is a relatively resource hungry process. If you close the database, then it will have to subsequently be opened at some expense.

As such you may wish to consider using a singleton (i.e. have a single instance of the opened database).

However, **ALWAYS** close a **Cursor** when done with it (which you are doing). A Cursor can be considered as a file and uses 1 of the limited available file allocations (about 1000 or so) for the operating system.

With regards to retrieving data from a Cursor, then rather than a moveToFirst and the do until moveToNext returns 0. You can simplify the code using `while(cursor.moveToNext) { .... }`. It is also inadvisable to use hard coded column offsets e.g. `bokmarks.setFileName(cursor.getString(1));` where 1 is the hard coded column offset and relies upon the 2nd column being the file name column and would have to be changed if the order of the columns in the cursor were to change. Instead you can utilise the `Cursor`'s `getColumnIndex` method to get the offset according to the column's name irrespective of it's position within the `Cursor`.

Putting the above together (making some assumptions) then you could have your class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper as (for example) :-

```
class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   public static final String DATABASE_FILENAME = "mydatabase.db";
   public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
   public static final String KEY_FILE_NAME = "kfn";
   public static final String KEY_FILE_URI = "kuri";
   public static final String KEY_FILE_PATH = "kpath";
   public static final String KEY_MONTH_NAME = "kmonth";
   public static final String KEY_DATE = "kdate";
   public static final String TABLE_DETAIL = "detail";

   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

   }

   private MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
      super(context,DATABASE_FILENAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
   }

   private static volatile MySQLiteOpenHelper instance;
   public static MySQLiteOpenHelper getMySQLiteOpenHelperInstance(Context context) {
      if (instance==null) {
         instance = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(context);
      }
      return instance;
   }

   public void insertData(List<ModelClass> list) {
      SQLiteDatabase dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
      dbase.beginTransaction();
      try {
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         for (ModelClass bokmark : list) {
            values.put(KEY_FILE_NAME, bokmark.getFileName());
            values.put(KEY_FILE_URI, String.valueOf(bokmark.getFileUri()));
            values.put(KEY_FILE_PATH, String.valueOf(bokmark.getFilePath()));
            values.put(KEY_MONTH_NAME, bokmark.getMonthName());
            values.put(KEY_DATE, bokmark.getAudioDate());

            dbase.insert(TABLE_DETAIL, null, values);
         }
         dbase.setTransactionSuccessful();
      } finally {
         dbase.endTransaction();
      }
      //dbase.close(); /* <<<<<<<<<< inefficient database will be closed when App is stopped as part of App cleanup */
   }

   public ArrayList<ModelClass> getAllData() {
      ArrayList<ModelClass> bookmarkList = new ArrayList<ModelClass>();
      String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DETAIL;
      //Log.e("selectQuery===>", "" + selectQuery);
      SQLiteDatabase dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

      // looping through all rows and adding to list
      /* <<<<<<<<<< get the column offsfets according to the column name rather than hard coding the offsets >>>>>>>>>> */
      int fnidx = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FILE_NAME);
      int uriidx = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FILE_URI);
      int fpidx = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FILE_PATH);
      int mnidx = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_MONTH_NAME);
      int didx = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);
      while (cursor.moveToNext()) { /*<<<<<<<<<< Simpler while loop */
         ModelClass bokmarks = new ModelClass();
         bokmarks.setFileName(cursor.getString(fnidx));
         bokmarks.setFileUri(parse(cursor.getString(uriidx)));
         bokmarks.setFilePath(cursor.getString(fpidx));
         bokmarks.setMonthName(cursor.getString(mnidx));
         bokmarks.setAudioDate(cursor.getString(didx));
         bookmarkList.add(bokmarks);
      }
      cursor.close();
      //dbase.close(); /* <<<<<<<<<< inefficient database will be closed when App is stopped as part of App cleanup */
      return bookmarkList;
   }
}
```

- ***Note** the above code is in-principle code, it has not been compiled and run so may contain some errors*

As for running in separate threads, there are many ways. Frequently the issue many encounter is understanding and coding for the detection and handling of the completion of the other thread, by the main thread, whenever that occurs.

I would suggest having a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads as a starting point.

Comment: Very helpful suggestions. can @MikeT guide me on adding and fetching data into sqlite table simultaneously and updating UI.